# Camel route test: Could not find a suitable setter for property:

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel, mockito

I have the next route with a bean for a searchTerm:

```
from( receiveProtocol+"://"+ipMailServer+"?username="+username+"&password="+password+"&"+options+"&searchTerm=#allowedAddresses")
```

The search term bean is like a spam filter: only accepts emails that are sent from a list of senders:

```
@Component
public class SpamFilter {

    @Value( "${spring.mailserver.spamfilter}")   String spamFilter; // Contains valid senders separated by comma.   

    @Bean
    public SearchTerm allowedAddresses() {

        String acceptedAddresses[]= spamFilter.split( ",");
        SearchTermBuilder build = new SearchTermBuilder();

        for ( int i= 0; i<acceptedAddresses.length; i++)
            build= build.from( Op.or, acceptedAddresses[ i].trim());

        return build.build();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine with the route and the search term. I created a unit test using Mockito that worked fine when the route did not contain the search term. I modified the test for mocking the search term, adding the next line:

```
@MockBean(name="allowedAddresses") SpamFilter spamFilter;
```

But I get the next exception:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route Email: Route(Email)[[From[imap://localhost?username=info@informer.d... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: imap://localhost?closeFolder=false&consumer.delay=10000&delete=false&disconnect=false&password=informer&peek=true&searchTerm=%23allowedAddresses&unseen=true&username=info%40informer.dispocargo.com due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: searchTerm as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: javax.mail.search.SearchTerm with value #allowedAddresses
```

I think I am missing mocking some method in my test, or maybe I am wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried using a newer version as it smells like a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: I was using 2.17.0. I moved to 2.24.2 and worked! Publish your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks Claus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried using a newer version as it smells like a bug that has been fixed.